# Rigorous definition of convergence in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

Let $\{u_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence in $H_{0}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, assume $u_{n}\to 0$ in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to clarify the definition of convergence in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$.
Does this convergence mean the following statement?
$\forall \phi \in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}),\, _{H^{-1}}\langle \phi,u_{n}\rangle_{H_{0}^{1}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ where $_{H^{-1}}\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle_{H_{0}^{1}}$ is the dual pairing of $H_{0}^{1}$ and $H^{-1}$.

Moreover, since we know that $H_{0}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert Space, can we say that it is equivalent to the notion of weak convergence instead?

Any help is pretty much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Usually $\to$ means strong/norm convergence, not weak convergence.

Comment: I am sorry but can you explain the relation between the norm in $H^{-1}$ and $H_{0}^{1}$ ? can I assume to be the same?

Comment: How do you define the space $H^{-1}$?

Comment: $H^{-1}$ is the dual space of $H_{0}^{1}$ in this case. My confusion arises from the fact that originally $u_{n} \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ but can we directly apply Riesz Representation Formula to identify it as an element of $H^{-1}$ to obtain a clear meaning of convergence?